# New add new option to a multi dropdown doenst show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add new options to a multi dropdown menu. Unfortunately the new added options do not show up. Only after selection a option in the dropdown menu they will appear.

That is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
          <label id="highway_label" for="highway_dropdown"></label>
          <select id="highway_dropdown" multiple data-native-menu="false">
            <option>highway</option>
            <option>highway</option>
           </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And if you do now this jquery: 
`$("#highway_dropdown").append("<option>Test1</option>");`

The new option "Test1" will only appear after you select the option "highway".

Here is my example code: https://jsfiddle.net/uzkbsevf/28/

Comment: Nothing shown would cause a duplication by itself. Also there are no nested `<div>` or `<ul>` in html shown as in the jQuery selectors. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uzkbsevf/22/

Comment: The minimal, complete, verifiable example must not be dependent on external resources. Try editing your question and using StackOverflow snippets instead (accessed by clicking the `|<>|` button when editing a question).

Comment: Is it now better?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

So the problem was that there is a bug in jquery.com/mobile therefore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has to do with jQuery Mobile re-creating the drop down. When you inspect the code, your Test1 element appears correctly, it's just not part of the `<ul>` jQuery Mobile creates.

Refresh the selectmenu after you append your option with this:

```
$("#highway_dropdown").selectmenu("refresh");
```

Your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzkbsevf/56/).